# Using REPLACE to add carriage returns to string not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

Where ever there is a '~' I want to put in a carriage return.

I want the data to look like this.

```
   Computer software for processing patient identification.
   On-demand printable wristband.
   Providing a web-based system and on-line Portal.
```

I've tried using the code below but the only thing it does is remove the '~'.

```
 SELECT REPLACE(' Computer software for processing patient identification.~  
 On-demand printable wristband.~  Providing a web-based system and on-line 
 Portal.~','~', CHAR(13)+CHAR(10));
```

Any idea how to add the carriage return?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

when I run your SQL Query and copy past the Query output into notpad++ with option "show END Line", I got below the screen. Your Query is correct.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are right (your query is correct and the other solution is also correct). I think the problem is that SQL Server Management Studio does not display the new lines correctly in grid mode.

Try the "Results to Text" option (in the "Query" / "Results to" menu), if you need to display only a single column. If you need to display multiple columns and at least one of them has newlines, you should use another tool to view the data. One solution would be to use the "Open in Excel" option provided by Red Gate SQL Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT REPLACE(' Computer software for processing patient identification.~  
 On-demand printable wristband.~  Providing a web-based system and on-line 
 Portal.~',
               '~', '
');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Management Studio, then change the settings: Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> Results to Grid -> Retain CR/LF on copy or save. Restart Management Studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BByv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for lack of response. Once the view, that has this code, was used in HotDocs they did show up in different lines. What was throwing me was when I put the returned rows in Notepad++ with view all symbols turned on I didn't see any CR or LR characters. That's why I thought it wasn't working.

Thanks for your responses!!

SR